# removing item from list (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table with car models in it. When a user clicks a car the selected car is shown in a list under the table. Now, i wanna so when the user clicks the car again it is removed from the list.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5wbeN/)

Comment: how are we supposed to help you with this information?

Comment: Here is the javascript http://pastebin.com/N4C743eP

Comment: Heres the html http://pastebin.com/aXe65NLh   I cant change anything in the html.  Its not added to a list sorry, it only appends to a div

Comment: @John: I edited your question to include something more useful than the pastebin dumps. Next time please just use http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com.

Comment: Yea, i was looking for that site xD Thanks alot man!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) ?

```
//DONNO WHAT TO PUT
$(this).remove();
```

**UPDATE**

Considering a non-dynamic table structure you can use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to safely pinpoint a row, uniquely. Combining it with an id (preferably starting with a unique string, as not to clash with the rest of your page, like `list_`) and remove(), you should get the required effect.

### Here's a [fork of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/S8NCF/).

Comment: xD that removes it from the table, not from the links at the bottom.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: nno, sorry if i wasn't clear. I want it to be removed from the links at the bottom. As you see when u click a row it that car gets added to a div under the table. I want it to be removed from that div

Comment: Updated my code then. See it on the fork. Gonna update my post if it's what you wanted.

Comment: It has a bug, due to the `<br />` at the end, I'd recommend using a <div> wrapper and removing that. Gonna do that in my fork for other people to have a clean result

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

I added a ref to the link you are adding to the row element, thus you can check for it and remove it:

```
function colorStay(){
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
    $(this).unbind('mouseover', changeColor);
    $(this).unbind('mouseout', removeColor);

    $('#stay').css({
        paddingTop:15,
        fontSize:22
    });
    var staylink = $("<a id='"+ $(this).find(':last').text() +"' href='http://www.google.ca'>"+ $(this).find(':last').text() +"</a><br />");
    $('#stay').append(staylink);
    $(this)[0].staylink = staylink;

}

function remove(){
    $(this).css('background-color','white');
    $(this).bind('mouseover', changeColor);
    $(this).bind('mouseout', removeColor);

    //DONNO WHAT TO PUT
    if($(this)[0].staylink){
        $(this)[0].staylink.remove();
        $(this)[0].staylink = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for showing me another way. Its always good to see other ways of doing thing!!! :D